# How to add custom application to context menu of all folders in Windows 7 to run with folder's path as parameter?

Tags: windows-7

I made an application that zips and puts any folder dropped onto it into backup folder on my disk. I'd like to be able to launch it with a parameter of a folder's full path via context menu.

How do I add my application to all folders' context menu and use the folder's path as a parameter in the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\myapp]
@="&MyApp"
"Icon"="shell32.dll,43"
"MultiSelectModel"="Single"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\myapp\command]
@="C:\\MyApp.bat \"%1\""
```

The above saved as a .REG file and imported into the registry will run your app and pass the full path of the selected folder to it as the first argument. Here's the content of **MyApp.bat** for testing:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (%*) do echo Argument = %%a
pause
```

Remove the **MultiSelectModel** line if you want the context menu entry to show up even when you select multiple folders and right-click.

However, this is more of a manual/hack-y method. I highly recommend you read the [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN article and ask over on StackOverflow about how to make your app's installer properly register your app as a valid context menu handler.